# TalkBack cannot announce column header when unordered list is in table

Tags: talkback

We have a pet table. We implement pet names as unordered list:

```html
<table>
    <caption>Pets</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>owner</th>
          <th>pets</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Amy</td>
        <td>
            <ul>
              <li>Piggy</li>
              <li>Tracy</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However when navigating the table, TalkBack are unable to announce the row id and the column header "Amy, row one, owner", just announce the content "Amy".

Change the unordered list to spans, the screen readers announce normally:

```html
<table>
    <caption>Pets</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>owner</th>
          <th>pets</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Amy</td>
        <td>
            <span>Piggy</span>
            <span>Tracy</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Should we prevent from unordered lists in table cells? Or is it a bug of TalkBack?

Comment: I just tried VoiceOver on iOS and I heard "**pets**, bullet, **column 2**, list start" when I swiped right to go to the second column.  If I swipe left back to the first column, I hear  "**owner**, amy, **column 1**".  So I'm hearing the column header "pets" and "owner" as well as the column number.  Perhaps you turned off your column headers and row id in your VoiceOver (and Talkback) settings?  On iOS, go to Settings > Accessibility > VoiceOver > Verbosity and scroll down to "Table Output".

Comment: @slugolicious Ah! Thank you for pointing that out. We test the VoiceOver again, and we found the VoiceOver announce the column header and column number normally in this case. Just Talkback failed. I correct the title.